# Reshape by creating a new variable

Tags: r

How do i transform the data by adding another variable called month to the below dataset

```
ID   Com    Lac   Nov(PM)    Nov(TM)  Dec(PM) Dec(TM)
1     A      E      12        11        28       29
2     B      F      2         13        26       44
3     C      G      7         15        18       37
4     D      H      4         10        22       22
```

Above is the data frame that needs to be transformed like below

```
ID   Com    Lac   Month    PM     TM
1    A       E     Nov      12    11
1    A       E     Dec      28    29
2    B       F     Nov      2     13
2    B       F     Dec      26    44
3    C       G     Nov      7     15
3    C       G     Dec      18    37
4    D       H     Nov      4     10
4    D       H     Dec      22    22
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Com = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Lac = c("E", 
 "F", "G", "H"), `Nov(PM)` = c(12L, 2L, 7L, 4L), `Nov(TM)` = c(11L, 
13L, 15L, 10L), `Dec(PM)` = c(28L, 26L, 18L, 22L), `Dec(TM)` = c(29L, 
44L, 37L, 22L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Can you use dput() to provide a reporducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We `gather` the columns 'Nov(PM)`to 'Dec(TM)` in to 'long' format, then using `extract`, split the 'key' column into 'Month' and another column, and finally `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
df1 %>%
   gather(key, val, `Nov(PM)`:`Dec(TM)`) %>% 
   extract(key, into = c('Month', 'key'), '^([^)]+)\\(([^)]+).*') %>% 
   spread(key, val)
#  ID Com Lac Month PM TM
#1  1   A   E   Dec 28 29
#2  1   A   E   Nov 12 11
#3  2   B   F   Dec 26 44
#4  2   B   F   Nov  2 13
#5  3   C   G   Dec 18 37
#6  3   C   G   Nov  7 15
#7  4   D   H   Dec 22 22
#8  4   D   H   Nov  4 10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Com = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Lac = c("E", 
 "F", "G", "H"), `Nov(PM)` = c(12L, 2L, 7L, 4L), `Nov(TM)` = c(11L, 
13L, 15L, 10L), `Dec(PM)` = c(28L, 26L, 18L, 22L), `Dec(TM)` = c(29L, 
44L, 37L, 22L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most evil and despised of all functions, `reshape`, handles this pretty well. So long as you spin the names around from `"Time(Variable)"` to `"Variable_Time"` it will process it all in one go:

```
names(df1) <- gsub("(.+?)\\((.+?)\\)", "\\2_\\1", names(df1))
reshape(df1, idvar=c("ID","Com","Lac"), varying=4:7,
        direction="long", sep="_", timevar="Month")

#          ID Com Lac Month PM TM
#1.A.E.Nov  1   A   E   Nov 12 11
#2.B.F.Nov  2   B   F   Nov  2 13
#3.C.G.Nov  3   C   G   Nov  7 15
#4.D.H.Nov  4   D   H   Nov  4 10
#1.A.E.Dec  1   A   E   Dec 28 29
#2.B.F.Dec  2   B   F   Dec 26 44
#3.C.G.Dec  3   C   G   Dec 18 37
#4.D.H.Dec  4   D   H   Dec 22 22
```

Comment: @akrun - i admit it is a bit tricky, but it is very flexible too! It doesn't have a lot of fans among R users so I like to throw in a tongue-in-cheek nod to its poor reputation.